# Replace \n with actual new line in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublimetext3

How can I replace `\n` in Sublime Text with real in-editor displayed new line so:

```
foo\nbar
```

becomes:

```
foo
bar
```

in the editor when I view the file in it.

Answer (score 981, accepted):

Turn on Regex Search and Replace (icon most to the left in search and replace bar or shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)

Find What: `\\n`
Replace with: `\n`

Comment: +1 to @ShahzadTariq as this doesn't work on Ubuntu Sublime, however the answer below from Sash does the trick just fine

Comment: To turn on Regex Search and Replace on Mac: `⌘` + `⌥` + `R`  :)

Comment: If this doesn't appear to be working, you might want to try replacing \n with your target string -- \\n replaces the actual sequence "\n" in the text content within your document, whereas \n replaces actual line breaks in the document.

Comment: Thanks, my Sublime died when I clicked Replace after almost 2'000'000 matches found

Comment: @SeniorJD sublime is pretty lightweight when it comes to handling large files. Maybe you could try something like `sed -i 's/\\n/\n/g' your_file.txt` which I guess could be more resource friendly.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. This finds "\\n" text instead and replaces it with text "\n"

Sash's answer works, however!

Answer (score 359):

Use `Find > Replace`, or (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>), to open the `Find What`/`Replace With` Window, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to indicate a new line in the `Replace With` inputbox.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `inoutbox`. Shift+Enter selects previous find in my Sublime3 setup if I type `\n` in `Find What` input.

Comment: I found that `\n` wasn't working for me with the regex button on, so this was very helpful.

Comment: This helped a ton, since I was trying to replace a vertical pipe `|` but regex was picking that up, so I had to turn off regex and use the Ctrl-Enter to add the new line. Thanks!

Comment: this worked in Visual Code too

Answer (score 66):

**Fool proof method** (no RegEx and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> didn't work for me as it was just jumping to next `Find`):

First, select an occurrence of `\n` and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> (brings up the `Replace...` dialogue, also accessible through `Find -> Replace...` menu). This populates the `Find what` field.

Go to the end of any line of your file (press <kbd>End</kbd> if your keyboard has it) and select the end of line by holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and pressing <kbd>→</kbd> (right arrow) **EXACTLY** once. Then copy-paste this into the `Replace with` field.

(the animation is for finding true new lines; works the same for replacing them)

[image]

Comment: I was on Ubuntu, and none of the other \r\n or \n works but this method is GOLDEN

Comment: the shortcut to "Use selection for Replace" is C-E or D-E (`Cmd` and upper case E)

Answer (score 27):

On Windows, Sublime text,

You press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to replace `\n` by a new line created by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Replace : `\n`

By : (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Comment: Works also in Ubuntu

Comment: This answer is very straight forward and should be given more importance. No beating around the bush. It works in Windows and Ubuntu.

Comment: works also on mac OS

Comment: this works with macOS others do not.

Answer (score 21):

In Sublime Text (with shortcuts on Mac):

0. Highlight the text that you want to search to apply Find & Replace
1. Go to Menu > Find > Replace... (Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>)
2. In the Find & Replace tool, enable Regular Expression by clicking on the button which looks like [.*] (Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>)
3. In Find What, type: `\\n`

   Note: The additional `\` escapes the Regular Expression syntax when searched.
4. In Replace With, type: `\n`
5. Click on the 'Replace All' button (Keyboard Shortcut: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

Your literal text `\n` will then turn into an actual line break.

Answer (score 14):

1. Open Find and Replace Option ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> in Mac )
2. Type `\n` in find input box
3. Click on Find All button, This will select all the `\n` in the text with the cursor
4. Now press Enter, this will replace `\n` with the New Line

Comment: Taking significant amount of time for large files but works for me while other answers didn't. Thank you

Answer (score 12):

What I did is simple and straightforward.

Enter `Space` or `\n` or whatever you want to find to Find.

Then hit `Find All` at right bottom corner, this will select all results.

Then hit `enter` on your keyboard and it will break all selected into new lines.

Answer (score 8):

For Windows line endings:

(Turn on regex - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>)

**Find**: `\\r\\n`

**Replace**: `\r\n`

[image: illustration]

Answer (score 7):

On Mac, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for search and replace. Search for `\n` and replace with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: This worked for me in Mac. Just replacing with `\n` did not for some reason.

Answer (score 6):

None of the above worked for me in Sublime Text 2 on Windows.

I did this:

- click on an empty line;
- drag to the following empty line (selecting the invisible character after the line);
- press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for replace;
- input desired replacement character/string or leave it empty;
- click "Replace all";

By selecting before hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> it uses that as the character to be replaced.

Comment: drag to the following empty line -> you can do the same doing 3 clicks over the line you want to copy (over text, over tabs works also, but no with spaces )

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way, you can copy the newline (copy empty 2 line in text editor) then paste on replace with.

Answer (score 3):

On MAC:

Step 1: <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> . At the bottom, a window appears
Step 2: Enable Regular Expression. Left side on the window, looks like .*
Step 3: Enter text to you want to find in the Find input field
Step 4: Enter replace text in the Replace input field
Step 5: Click on Replace All - Right bottom.

[image: replace field]

Answer (score 1):

ctrl+h

sample :
type: </>
replace: \n

down below , find button - change to ALT+R
you see changed eFFect in color , better to use sample

nice feature

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).